# Created a new TFS Project with Incorrect Process Template

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2015, tfs, process, scrum

I created a new TFS 2015 Project with the incorrect Process Template.  Usually I would delete the Project and re-add with the correct Process Template but a user has already spent 20 plus hours creating Epics, Features, User Stories, Tasks and Sprints.  I cant have him redo his work.

It appears like there is no way to change the Process Template for an existing Project so all I really need to do is update the SCRUM Process Template Task.xml with the custom Process Template Task.xml and upload but I cant figure out how to do this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WITADMIN](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/witadmin-customize-and-manage-objects-for-tracking-work), which is part of every Visual Studio install.

Something like this should do the trick: `witadmin importwitd /collection:<URL> /p:<Team Project> /f:<Path to work item XML file>`